# Discrepancy between my SQL python data and the DB Browser

Tags: python, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I am using sqlite combined with tkinter to write and delete records within my Python program. The deletion works perfectly fine in my program and also when I restart the program, the record does not exist anymore.
However, I always cross check using the Linux standard software DB Browser for SQLite and look at my SQL Table. Strangely, all records still exist in the DB Browser. Now I am wondering, why's that? Why is it gone within my Python sqlite queries but not in the DB Browser? Somehow the records are still there. How can I completely destroy my records?

For deletion I use:
(The user can chose a specific entry using a listbox. Eventually, I "translate" the selected item into its specific ID and trigger the deletion.)

```
self.c.execute("DELETE FROM financial_table WHERE ID=?",(entry,))
self.conn.commit()
```

For my query I use:
(I query the data for a specific year and month.)

```
self.c.execute("SELECT ID, Date, Item, Price FROM financial_table WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', Date) = '{}' ORDER BY Date ".format(date))
single_dates = self.c.fetchall()
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: To understand what is going wrong we need the code you are using @Bahlsen.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my question is: I am stupid!
I was tired yesterday evening and looked at the wrong sql file in a subfolder which had the same name than the one from my python program. So it is actually working. Please excuse my stupidity.

@Bruceskyaus
Despite my stupidity I learned from your answer, especially the try ... except block. I am going to implement it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an problem with controlling transactions on your database, but it could also be the connection itself. Make sure you don't have any uncommitted DML statements on a different connection (i.e. an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` in your DB Browser that wasn't committed), this could cause the `conn.commit()` to fail. With SQLite, an uncommitted transaction could lock the entire database - for a brief period of time.

Try ensuring that there is a new cursor for the delete statement and call `conn.close()` after the `conn.commit()`. Before you execute the code, make sure that no other connections are accessing the database - including the DB Browser. Only check in the DB Browser when you have shut down the application (for this test). This eliminates multithreading or locking as a possible cause. See also [SQLite - Data Persistence](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html) and [SQLite - Controlling Transactions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions)

It is also helpful to trap all errors for DML statements using a `try...except` block. Something like this:

```
import sqlite3

try:
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
    self.c = conn.cursor()    
    self.c.execute("DELETE FROM financial_table WHERE ID=?",(entry,))
    self.conn.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e.args[0])
finally:
    self.conn.close()
```